# Flutter base64 pdf view and download

Tags: flutter

Here comes the pdf converted to base64 from an API. I cannot view and download from within the application. I would be glad if you help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: hello, did you manage to do it??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to add "*path_provider*" and "*open_file*"

```
dependencies:
  path_provider: ^2.0.9
  open_file: ^3.2.1
```

Then create new class

```
 class FileProcess {
  static bool isFolderCreated = false;
  static Directory? directory;

  static checkDocumentFolder() async {
    try {
      if (!isFolderCreated) {
        directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
        await directory!.exists().then((value) {
          if (value) directory!.create();
          isFolderCreated = true;
        });
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
    }
  }

  static Future<File> downloadFile() async {
    final base64str = "put your base64 value";
    Uint8List bytes = base64.decode(base64str);
    await checkDocumentFolder();
    String dir =
        directory!.path + "/" + "your file name" + ".pdf";
    File file = new File(dir);
    if (!file.existsSync()) file.create();
    await file.writeAsBytes(bytes);
    return file;
  }
}
```

After you create the class you can use it **for download** your pdf.

**For open** the file add this lines into your class

```
static void openFile(String fileName) {
        String dir =
            directory!.path + "/${fileName}.pdf";
        OpenFile.open(dir));
      }
```

After all you can use like

```
await FileProcess.downloadFile()
```

and

```
FileProcess.openFile(fileName)
```

These codes should be working.

Comment: There is actually a problem. When the number of Base64 characters is high, I get the error "Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Invalid length, must be multiple of four (at character 57543)".

if (base64str.length % 4 > 0) {
      base64str += '=' * (4 - base64str .length % 4);
    }

I added like this, but I still get the error

..jU1YTI4OThjZjgzYTc2NWVhODQzZmMzNGIzYTcwPl0vUm9vdCAyMyAwIFIvU2l6ZSAyNT4+Cn==

Comment: You can use "base64str = base64.normalize(base64str );". Dont forget to import 'dart:convert'

Comment: Unfortunately nothing has changed. The error i got "E/flutter (19054): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Invalid encoding before padding (at character 57543)
E/flutter (19054): ...jU1YTI4OThjZjgzYTc2NWVhODQzZmMzNGIzYTcwPl0vUm9vdCAyMyAwIFIvU2l6ZSAyNT4+Cn=="

Comment: This is how it worked.

if (base64str.length % 4 > 0) {
      base64str += '+' * (4 - base64str .length % 4);
    }